# Access remote Windows PC command line without launching full remote desktop?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, vnc, remote, realvnc

Is there a way to log into a remote Windows PC and access that PC's command prompt without launching "Remote Desktop"?  Note that installing servers/services on the remote PC, which would run without already having a user logged in, is not an option.  This would need to be a capability that is accessible in base Windows 7.

My goal is to be able to log into the remote Windows PC, start RealVNC Server through a command line, and remain logged in with my credentials - all without causing Remote Desktop to forward the display to my local computer (Remote Desktop, hopefully just the display part, and VNC Server appear to not work simultaneously).

Comment: Why can't you configure the VNC server service to start automatically so that none of this is necessary?

Comment: Work PC - they take all our privileges away.

Comment: Does this mean that the only way you can get the service to run is by first interactively logging into the machine? Or do you have sufficient privileges to start the service but just not enough to configure it to start automatically?

Comment: Now I can't remember if, once I'm logged in, I'm running VNC Server in User Mode or Service Mode.  I'll check on Monday...  Regardless, the issue that I'm trying to work around is that if I start the server from a Remote Desktop session, VNC client connections fail  (even when I close the Remote Desktop session while remaining logged in).  If I log into the PC by physically being in front of it and then start the server, VNC connections succeed.

Comment: That's because VNC connects users to the *console* (same as an interactive login), whereas Remote Desktop connects a user to a non-console session. You really need to get VNC configured to run automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Download PSTools from Microsoft Technet.  The PSexec tool will do what you want, acting in the remote machine but showing you the command shell locally.  For example :
C:\Users\username>C:\Users\username\Downloads\Tools\PSTools\PsExec64.exe \REMOTEPC cmd 
C:\Windows\system32>wmic cpu get name

Comment: Will that keep me logged in on the remote PC?  I do not have full admin privileges (I have some privileges but they're restricted) - do I need those to set up the tools on either PC?

Comment: My apologies, I assumed you had priviledges on both PCs.  It's not guaranteed, but worth trying.

Comment: You need admin privileges on the remote PC to connect with psexec.